# User getting disabled

Tags: java, angular, spring

I have been working with an Angular project and their is user which is getting disabled while logging in.

The error log i have got is :

```
[10/12/23 13:27:57:765 GMT-07:00] 00000183 BasicResource W com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask run com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@e0972d2d -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
                                 java.sql.SQLException: The application server rejected the connection. (User ID is disabled.:CUSTSERV)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.createSQLExceptionSubClass(JDError.java:820)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:549)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.setProperties(AS400JDBCConnection.java:3342)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.prepareConnection(AS400JDBCDriver.java:1419)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.initializeConnection(AS400JDBCDriver.java:1256)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.connect(AS400JDBCDriver.java:395)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner$TaskThread.run(ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner.java:255)
Caused by: com.ibm.as400.access.AS400SecurityException: User ID is disabled.:CUSTSERV
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.returnSecurityException(AS400ImplRemote.java:2096)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.signon(AS400ImplRemote.java:2407)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.sendSignonRequest(AS400.java:3181)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.promptSignon(AS400.java:2745)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.signon(AS400.java:4076)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.connectService(AS400.java:1203)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.setProperties(AS400JDBCConnection.java:3338)
```

I want why does the User is getting disabled

Comment: Because an AS400 admin disabled it?

Comment: How come we can tell that the AS400 admin disabled it

Comment: The error indicates that the user is disabled on the AS400; talk to the server administrator.  If that person is you, enable the account on the AS400.